# php show 3 dates : Next Wednesday, Saturday, Sunday (include today)

Tags: php

Currently i wrote very long codes :

```
if ($today_day == "Wednesday"){
  //show today date, show next saturday date, show next sunday date
}elseif ($today_day == "Saturday"){
  //show today date, show next Sunday date, show next Wednesday date
}elseif ($today_day == "Sunday"){
  //show today date, show next Wednesday date, show next Saturday date
}else{
  //show next Wednesday date, show next Saturday date, show next Sunday date
}
```

Any other solution for this? I want to shorten the code.

Comment: Have a look here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ and here is the base https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could definitely clean this up by compiling all three, indexed by their day code and then just redeclare the current day with today if it matches:

```
 $dates = [
    '3' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next wednesday + 1 week")),
    '5' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next saturday + 1 week")),
    '6' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next sunday + 1 week"))
 ];
 
 $today = date('N');
 
 if (isset( $dates[$today])) {
     $dates[$today] = date('Y-m-d');
 }
 
 var_dump($dates); // Or whatever you want to do with it afterwards
```

Comment: Are u compare today with next week Wednesday?
It is not compare with THIS week Wednesday.

Comment: @ZacAng So all days will be the next one, except if today is that day - So if it's Wednesday today, the end result will be 3 => Today, 5 => Next Saturday, 6 => Next Sunday

Answer (score 0):

Here try the below solution:

```
if ($today_day == "Wednesday"){
  //show today date, show next saturday date, show next sunday date
   $today = date('Y-m-d');
   $next_saturday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next saturday + 1 week"));
   $next_sunday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next sunday + 1 week"));
}
elseif ($today_day == "Saturday"){
  //show today date, show next Sunday date, show next Wednesday date
   $today = date('Y-m-d');
   $next_wednesday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next wednesday + 1 week"));
   $next_sunday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next sunday + 1 week"));
}
elseif ($today_day == "Sunday"){
  //show today date, show next Wednesday date, show next Saturday date
   $today = date('Y-m-d');
   $next_wednesday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next wednesday + 1 week"));
   $next_saturday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next saturday + 1 week"));
}
else{
  //show next Wednesday date, show next Saturday date, show next Sunday date
   $next_saturday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next saturday + 1 week"));
   $next_wednesday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next wednesday + 1 week"));
   $next_sunday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next sunday + 1 week"));
}
```